# Jquery Show Image Before .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, spinner

I know this has been asked quite a bit , but I need to as simply as possible show a loading image before the content is loaded, exactly how Facebook's signup form is and many other sites.

```
    $("#signUpPanel").click(function(){
      $("#headInner").html("<img class='spinner' src='imgs/spinner.gif'>");
        $("#headInner").load("signUp.php");
 });
```

This is what I have thus far and it displays, but its nearly impossible to even see it. I was thinking of using the delay() function or something similiar, thanks in advance and keep it as simple as possible if you can.

Comment: Showing an image while something is loading seems a good thing to do, but intentionally slowing down how fast something loads to show the image seems rather anti-productive. If you have an actual delay the image will show but if your page loads in 0.0001 seconds you should be happy and not try to make it look like your page takes longer to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#signUpPanel").click(function(){
  $("#headInner").html("<img class='spinner' src='imgs/spinner.gif'>");
  setTimeout(function(){$("#headInner").load("signUp.php");},1000);  
 });
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was going for, I really appreciate it

Comment: If this fixed your issue, how about accepting one of the answers:)

Answer (score 3):

You should pre-load the image somewhere before the click is triggered
Why use a delay, no one wants to wait extra time just see a loading image, if the contents load fast enough not to see the loading image you should be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Right way:

```
 $("#signUpPanel").click(function(){
     // in this way after image loaded, page will be load ...
     $('<img class='spinner' src='imgs/spinner.gif' />').load(function(){
         $("#headInner").html($(this));
         $("#headInner").load("signUp.php");
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding to the dom. You need to do this.

```
$('#headerInner').addClass('loadingClass');

.loadingClass { background-image: url('imgs/spinner.gif') }

$('#headerInner').removeClass('loadingClass');
```

Comment: This is the simplest straight forward code. With it as a background image you can have it show up where you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('<img/>')[0].src = 'imgs/spinner.gif'; //preload
    img.className = 'spinner'; //add class

$("#signUpPanel").on('click', function(){
    $("#headInner").html(img).load("signUp.php"); //load will remove the image
});
```

If it's impossible to even see it, the load is fast enough that it's usually a bad idea with a spinner.

Delaying a function just to show of your cool spinner is the opposite of enhancing your website.